# How to concatenate the function argument and input id.

Tags: javascript

```
var i;
for (i=2; i<=32; i++){
var j=i-1;
document.writeln("<td  align=\"center\"><input type=\"text\"      onblur=\"add3('p4rm2r'+i,'p3rm2r'+j,this)\" size=\"1\" maxlength=\"4\"></td><td align=\"center\"><input     type=\"text\"   onblur=\"subs1('p3rm2r'+i,'p4rm2r'+i,this)\" size=\"1\" maxlength=\"4\"></td><td align=\"center\"> <input type=\"text\" id=\" 'p3rm2r' +i\"  readonly  size=\"1\" maxlength=\"4\" ></td><td align=\"center\"><input type=\"text\" id=\" 'p4rm2r' +i\" readonly size=\"1\" maxlength=\"4\"></td></tr>"  );
}
```

I guess there are some mistake in the syntax, specially in the caoncatenation. My intention is to concatenate the function argument and input id.  e.g I want to use p4rm2r2, p4rm2r3, p4rm2r4, ..p4rm2r32 as function arguments and as input id. Please suggest me the correct syntax.

Comment: What function input?

Comment: The issue is in the concatenation where you have mixed up single and double quotes, so the p4rm2r and such don't get the 2, 3, 4 appended correctly. Look at my answer and see if that makes it a little clearer how to correctly concatenate.

Answer (score 0):

********EDIT*******

```
var i;
for (i=2; i<=32; i++){
var j=i-1;
    document.writeln("<td  align=\"center\"><input type=\"text\"     onblur=\"add3('p4rm2r" + i + "','p3rm2r" + j + "',this)\"size=\"1\"maxlength=\"4\"></td><td align=\"center\"><input     type=\"text\"  onblur=\"subs1('p3rm2r" + i + "','p4rm2r" + i + "',this)\"size=\"1\"maxlength=\"4\"></td><td align=\"center\"> <input type=\"text\"id=\"p3rm2r" + i + "\" readonly  size=\"1\"maxlength=\"4\"></td><td align=\"center\"><input type=\"text\"id=\"p4rm2r" + i + "\"readonly size=\"1\"maxlength=\"4\"></td></tr>"  );
}
```

As I said on how you write it is pretty missy and I stated that you have you quote not properly typed.  I did the work for you since you didn't even bother correcting these typos you have and this is what I get in the inputs when running the new code above that I cleaned for you.  Running the code it produces these input elements. (I didn't write the td in the output but it should be there when you run your script)

As I said you are not properly writing your quotes

```
<input type="text" onblur="add3('p4rm2r2','p3rm2r1',this)" size="1" maxlength="4">
<input type="text" onblur="subs1('p3rm2r2','p4rm2r2',this)" size="1" maxlength="4">
<input type="text" id="p3rm2r2" readonly="" size="1" maxlength="4">
<input type="text" id="p4rm2r2" readonly="" size="1" maxlength="4">    
<input type="text" onblur="add3('p4rm2r3','p3rm2r2',this)" size="1" maxlength="4">
<input type="text" onblur="subs1('p3rm2r3','p4rm2r3',this)" size="1" maxlength="4">
<input type="text" id="p3rm2r3" readonly="" size="1" maxlength="4">
<input type="text" id="p4rm2r3" readonly="" size="1" maxlength="4">
```

Comment: @suvadip I changed my answer, check it and run also check the result I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?
I tried to simplify the concatenation. Like Andrex said, use single quotes around the whole thing when you want to use double quotes inside, so you don't have to use the escape `\"` character.

```js
var i;
for (i = 2; i <= 32; i++) {
    var j = i - 1;
    document.writeln('<td align="center">' +
        '<input type="text"' +
        'onblur="add3("p4rm2r' + i + '","p3rm2r' + j + '",this)"' +
        'size="1" maxlength="4"> </td> <td align="center"> <input type="text"' +
        'onblur="subs1("p3rm2r' + i + '","p4rm2r' + i + '",this)"' +
        'size="1" maxlength="4"> </td> <td align="center"> <input type="text"' +
        'id="p3rm2r' + i + '"' +
        'readonly size="1" maxlength="4"> </td> <td align="center"> <input type="text"' +
        'id="p4rm2r' + i + '"' +
        'readonly size="1" maxlength="4"> </td></tr>');
}
```

Comment: @suvadip You should probably provide more details as to what is "not working" for you.